# How to Design This Arrow mention Shape In xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

[image]

> I have Tried with PancakeView and Frame But i did't create the type of
> shape in red anyone please can make this red shaped background in
> Xamarin.forms with Xaml.

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you could use **Shapes** . Xamarin.Forms Shapes is currently experimental and can only be used by setting the **Shapes_Experimental** flag.  So add the line `Forms.SetFlags("Shapes_Experimental");` in all platforms .

#### in iOS -> AppDelegate.cs

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {


            Forms.SetFlags("Shapes_Experimental");
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

#### in Android -> MainActivity

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Forms.SetFlags("Shapes_Experimental");
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

#### in xaml

```
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="200" />

        <Ellipse Fill="Red"
                
                 Margin="0,-90,0,0"                    
                 HeightRequest="180"
                 WidthRequest="1000"
               />

    </StackLayout>
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JMEB.png)